# Can't assign requested address in logical system

Tags: juniper

I just configured logical system but cannot ping between two routers logical and it shows the message: "Can't assign requested address".
My configuration is as follows:

```
set logical-systems r1 interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 17 vlan-id 17
set logical-systems r1 interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 17 family inet address 10.0.17.1/24  
set logical-systems r7 interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 17 vlan-id 17
set logical-systems r7 interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 17 family inet address 10.0.17.7/24
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 vlan-tagging
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 vlan-tagging
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it could be one of three things:

Firstly, what platform are you testing this on and does it support logical systems?

Secondly, do you have interface `ge-0/0/0` physically patched to `ge-0/0/1`?

Finally, are you using the correct command to ping e.g.:

`ping logical-system r1 10.0.17.7`

Answer (score 0):

Or..Try specifying the outgoing interface in the ping command for example
ping {ip-address} interface ge-0/0/0
ping {ip-address} interface ge-0/0/1

Comment: It certainly does answer the question. I have offered an exact solution to the problem posed in the original question